# yaml dump complex number

Tags: python, yaml

I loaded a complex number in my yaml structure, and when dumping it, the output is not exactly what I'd like to have :

```py
obj={'val': -0.3+0.1j}                                                                                                                                                               
yaml.dump(obj, default_flow_style=False)                                                                                                                                             
"val: !!python/complex '-0.3+0.1j'\n"
```

I'd like to have directly :

```
val: -0.3+0.1j
```

I tried to write a `complex_represented()` function but without success. The best I can do is cast the complex number to string and remove parentheses.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked but seems a bit awful :

```py
def complex_representer(dumper, value):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', str(value)[1:-1])

yaml.add_representer(complex, complex_representer)
```